# Swift:Return UItable view Delegates and data Source

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a main viewController that is table View Controller. I have two nib files. One of the nib contains a table view inside it. I wanted to keep the data inside that table view. I am confused how to return UItable view delegates and datasource from nib file to mainView.

Here is my code:

```
var participationList : ["Apple","Dog","cat","Mat"]
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if  indexPath.row == 0
    {
      //first cell
    }
    if indexPath.row == 1
    {
      let cell : ActivitySecondTableViewCell = (NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("ActivitySecondTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil).first as? ActivitySecondTableViewCell)!
      cell.textLabel?.text = self.participationList[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

    let cell : ActivitySecondTableViewCell = (NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("IncentiveActivitySecondTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil).first as? IncentiveActivitySecondTableViewCell)!
    return cell
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return 2

}
```

this is my main table View controller and i am returning the cells from here. The cells are clearly displayed here. And ActivitySecondTableViewCell contains Table view inside it.

This is my nib:

```
class ActivitySecondTableViewCell: UITableViewCell,UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var CellTableView: UITableView!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.CellTableView.delegate = self
        // Initialization code
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return "Required Health Activities for 2017"
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view:UIView, forSection: Int) {
        if let headerTitle = view as? UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
            headerTitle.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
        }
    }
    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
    }
```

I can neither see the title in Activitysecond cell nor the data.How can i achive them??

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've more than 2 rows in your first tableview and then inherit secondTableView cell with UITableViewDataSource and give some numberOfRows just for the sake of checking and return UITableViewCell in cellForRowAt and check if you can see something happening.

Comment: how can i give the numberOfRows to secondTableViewCell,??

Comment: In your ActivitySecondTableViewCell start typing numberOfRows and that way you can define numberOfRows. If suggestions aren't coming then inherit ActivitySecondTableViewCell with UITableViewDataSource and then check.

Comment: yes. I passed the data from main table view  to Activity cell and i did it. Thanks your advice also helped me :) :) :)

Answer (score 0):

For different Nib you can use as this

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


if indexPath.row == 1
{
  let cell : ActivitySecondTableViewCell = (NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("ActivitySecondTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil).first as? ActivitySecondTableViewCell)!
  cell.textLabel?.text = self.participationList[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
 else
{
   let cell : ActivitySecondTableViewCell = (NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("IncentiveActivitySecondTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil).first as? IncentiveActivitySecondTableViewCell)!
  return cell
}
}
```